# heroku showing There's nothing here, yet even though app is deployed and worked properly

Tags: heroku

I have used heroku for 2 months now. Deployed one app, everything worked fine.

I actually already finished app development 2 days ago. Everything worked fine also yesterday. Suddenly today I checked app today and got violet screen telling There's nothing here, yet.

[image]

I not aware of any changes I did.

The app is connected to github and saying it is successfully deployed:
[image]

But when I click view I am getting an error mentioned above.

I am using hobby dynos and 2 addons:
[image]

I also checked the log, but not sure when the error happened. It seems everything worked fine or Thursday when somebody used the page then something happened but not sure if it is sth wrong:

```
2021-05-13T11:12:50.762433+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.35.82.179 - vacuumlabs [13/May/2021:11:12:50 +0000] "POST /custom HTTP/1.1" 200 24330 "https://vacuumlabs-recruitment-stats.herokuapp.com/custom" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36"
```

2021-05-13T11:12:50.763448+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/custom" host=vacuumlabs-recruitment-stats.herokuapp.com request_id=7d49caa2-f822-4337-b00e-127c18771d99 fwd="46.229.238.250" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=7103ms status=200 bytes=24507 protocol=https
2021-05-13T11:17:58.381694+00:00 app[web.1]: post
2021-05-13T11:17:58.507274+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.14.65.222 - vacuumlabs [13/May/2021:11:17:58 +0000] "POST /custom HTTP/1.1" 200 71394 "https://vacuumlabs-recruitment-stats.herokuapp.com/custom" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36"
2021-05-13T11:17:58.509324+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/custom" host=vacuumlabs-recruitment-stats.herokuapp.com request_id=4192a1fd-a3f6-485f-b1fa-f4608158201d fwd="46.229.238.250" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=658ms status=200 bytes=71571 protocol=https
2021-05-13T11:24:14.596255+00:00 app[worker.1]: 11:24:14 Cleaning registries for queue: default
2021-05-13T11:51:14.964091+00:00 app[worker.1]: 11:51:14 Cleaning registries for queue: default
2021-05-13T12:18:15.365521+00:00 app[worker.1]: 12:18:15 Cleaning registries for queue: default
2021-05-13T12:45:15.807208+00:00 app[worker.1]: 12:45:15 Cleaning registries for queue: default
2021-05-13T13:12:16.162276+00:00 app[worker.1]: 13:12:16 Cleaning registries for queue: default
2021-05-13T13:22:19.752760+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Cycling
2021-05-13T13:22:19.758617+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2021-05-13T13:22:21.404441+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2021-05-13T13:22:21.468764+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-05-13 13:22:21 +0000] [19] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 19)
2021-05-13T13:22:21.469338+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-05-13 13:22:21 +0000] [18] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 18)
2021-05-13T13:22:21.603043+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2021-05-13T13:22:29.506983+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `flask db upgrade; gunicorn run:app`
2021-05-13T13:22:44.229806+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
2021-05-13T13:22:44.229847+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
2021-05-13T13:22:45.237101+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-05-13 13:22:45 +0000] [16] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2021-05-13T13:22:45.238104+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-05-13 13:22:45 +0000] [16] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:48000 (16)
2021-05-13T13:22:45.238263+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-05-13 13:22:45 +0000] [16] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2021-05-13T13:22:45.251720+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-05-13 13:22:45 +0000] [18] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 18
2021-05-13T13:22:45.281325+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-05-13 13:22:45 +0000] [19] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 19
2021-05-13T13:22:45.368368+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-05-13T13:39:16.610272+00:00 app[worker.1]: 13:39:16 Cleaning registries for queue: default

Then at night a cron job started an ran properly if I understand correctly:

```
2021-05-14T01:48:26.272275+00:00 app[worker.1]: 01:48:26 Cleaning registries for queue: default
```

2021-05-14T02:00:25.490758+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `python3 web/scheduler.py` by user scheduler@addons.heroku.com
2021-05-14T02:00:33.513008+00:00 heroku[scheduler.9441]: Starting process with command `python3 web/scheduler.py`
2021-05-14T02:00:34.559803+00:00 heroku[scheduler.9441]: State changed from starting to up
2021-05-14T02:00:41.805043+00:00 app[worker.1]: 02:00:41 default: web.recruit_app.update_data(limit=100000, update=True) (1ca05337-8b3f-4c1a-b266-0b0b883ebc3b)
2021-05-14T02:00:41.962375+00:00 heroku[scheduler.9441]: Process exited with status 0
2021-05-14T02:00:42.013109+00:00 heroku[scheduler.9441]: State changed from up to complete

Then sth happened in the morning:

2021-05-14T04:12:04.744216+00:00 app[worker.1]: 04:12:04 Cleaning registries for queue: default
2021-05-14T04:36:22.931198+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Relocating dyno to a new server
2021-05-14T04:36:22.947164+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2021-05-14T04:36:22.965859+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2021-05-14T04:36:28.769921+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `flask db upgrade; gunicorn run:app`
2021-05-14T04:36:34.945926+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
2021-05-14T04:36:34.945980+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
2021-05-14T04:36:35.586629+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-05-14 04:36:35 +0000] [16] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2021-05-14T04:36:35.587223+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-05-14 04:36:35 +0000] [16] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:34427 (16)
2021-05-14T04:36:35.587345+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-05-14 04:36:35 +0000] [16] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2021-05-14T04:36:35.595662+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-05-14 04:36:35 +0000] [18] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 18
2021-05-14T04:36:35.685214+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-05-14 04:36:35 +0000] [19] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 19
2021-05-14T04:36:35.753571+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-05-14T04:37:06.119631+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2021-05-14T04:37:08.022638+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2021-05-14T04:39:05.134774+00:00 app[worker.1]: 04:39:05 Cleaning registries for queue: default

After that nothing else in log.

Where can be the problem please?

Comment: Please, see the logs with the CLI command 'heroku logs' or selecting More -> View logs in heroku dashboard. Check if there's any error there.
From what I have searched, that error may happen if you set a custom domain, have you set one or do you stick with herokuapp.com?

Comment: No I havent chenged the domain I use heroku domain.
I just added useful parts of log into the question

Comment: It seems that what just some issue on heroku side, because I haven't tried to change anything last 2 days and somehow everything works fine again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same trouble with my application!

But after a couple of hours from changes where done the application became available.

Just wait for some hours.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Heroku CLI to [delete the app](https://help.heroku.com/LGKL6LTN/how-do-i-delete-destroy-a-heroku-application), then recreate it and push to heroku.

Comment: This works for me. No errors in my logs. Sucks, but hey, it's free and it works pretty well most of the time. Gitbash support could be better though. I keep having to open up powershell for certain commands to avoid hanging the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

The same happen to me with two review apps I was deploying at the same time and as User 502 said, after a couple of hours both became availables.